# Better way in Python

Tags: python, bash

Is there a better / simpler way to accomplish this in Python?

I have a bash script that calculates CPS (calls per second).  It runs fine on small files but poorly on large ones.  It basically takes the file that we are calculating the CPS for and extracts field 7 which is the INVITING time, sorts, and only gets the unique values.  This is all put in a tmp.file.  The script then cats the original file and greps for each of the values in the tmp.file, counts them, and outputs the time and count to a final file.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 |cut -d "," -f 7 | sort |uniq > /tmp/uniq.time.txt;
list="/tmp/uniq.time.txt";

while read time
    do
    VALUE1=`cat $1 |grep "$time" |wc -l`;
    echo $VALUE1 >> /tmp/cps.tmp;
done < $list;

rm /tmp/cps.tmp;
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Voice over IP?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I believe a "call" in this case is a VoIP call record.

Comment: This does not say how you're calculating "calls per second". For example, I would interpret "calls per second" to be the equivalent of counting all the calls, and dividing it by the time between the first and last call. If you are attempting to do some kind of moving average or something, you have to say so. Additionally you should say why you need to uniquify everything; aren't those calls as well, or are they duplicates for some reason?

Comment: There really is not any calculation done.  I am simply getting the INVITING time of the call (field 7) and then grepping that value on my original file.  The reason I am getting the unique values for the time is because I only need one instance of it to grep and count on my original file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is simply:

```
cat $1 |cut -d "," -f 7 | sort | uniq -c
```

note: if you want to swap the order of the fields:

```
| awk -F " *" '{print $3, $2}'
```

Comment: Nice, this is certainly the way to go here!  Didn't know about the `-c` option.

Comment: Thanks! The uniq -c option is great.  This works so much better than going line by line.

Answer (score 1):

This can certainly be done easier and more efficiently in Python:

```
import sys
from itertools import groupby

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    times = [line.split(",")[6] for line in f]
times.sort()
for time, occurrences in groupby(times):
    print time, len(list(occurrences))
```

The problem with your approach is that you have to serach the whole file for each unique time.  You could write this more efficiently even in bash, but I think it's more convenient to do this in Python.

Answer (score -1):

Reading CSV files:

> http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Uniquifying:

```
set(nonUniqueItems)
```

Comment: Uniquifying is a bad idea.  It discards the frequencies the OP is interested in.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: perhaps, depending on whether they are in fact duplicates or actual calls. But the OP was doing it, so if I'm wrong then he's wrong. The question really should be improved.

Comment: The OP first uniquified, then counted how often each time occurs.  this is certainly not optimal.

Comment: It doesn't seem unoptimal to me (no asymptotic complexity added); it just seems it might be wrong and unnecessary. I could add a giant disclaimer in my answer "Uniquifying (**why are you doing this? it might be wrong**):" but that seems unnecessary to me. =) At least until they edit their answer to elaborate what on earth they're doing.

Comment: Since I assume that the number of unique times scales with total number of records, it *does* add asymptotic complexity -- it will be O(n^2) instead of O(n).

Comment: If the duplicate record list scales `O(N^2)` the OP would run out of disk space. Even if every entry was identical you wouldn't have issues depending on what exactly the OP is trying to do. This discussion (which I'd prefer not to have) is pointless without knowing how the records actually scale.

Comment: What I mean is that O(n^2) is the *runtime* of the OP's code, not the disk usage, where n is the number of records.  (S)he iterates over all records for each unique time, which is most probably O(n^2).  Well, be it.